# jQuery doesn't .load() until .ajax() within callback of .load() is complete?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My problem is that the `<div>` with the jQuery progress bar (`dnc_scrubber.html`) isn't loaded until all of the other requests are complete.

Is there anyway around this?  I want to change the content of `#tabs-1` to the progress bar, and animate it while `dnc_scrubber.php` is doing its work.

The `lines.php` and `progress.php` files are used to calculate the percentage of work done by `dnc_scrubber.php` - which updates the session as it goes along.  `lines.php` and `files.php` return the session variable.

```
$('#tabs-1').load('dnc_scrubber.html', function() {
    var querystring = 'col=' + col + '&' + makeQS(files);
    var lines = 0;

    $('#progressbar').progressbar();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'dnc_scrubber.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: querystring,
        complete: function() {
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                $('#complete').append('<a href="process/MATCHED - ' + files[i] + '">MATCHED - ' + files[i] + '</a><br />');
                $('#complete').append('<a href="process/SCRUBBED - ' + files[i] + '">SCRUBBED - ' + files[i] + '</a><br />');
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'lines.php',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(json) {
            lines = json.total;
        }
    });


    function setProgress() {
        if (prog < lines) {
            prog = getProgress();
            $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', prog);
            setTimeout(setProgress(), 1000)
        } else {
            $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', 100);
        }
    }

    var prog = getProgress();
    setTimeout(setProgress(), 1000);
});
```

I have already tried loading the progress bar within the callback function of a `.ajax()` request with `async` set to `false`.  The same result happens - the progress bar is not loaded into `#tabs-1` until `dnc_scrubber.php` is complete.

What can I do?

Comment: You know what synchronous and asynchronous requests are?

Comment: Have you tried using the success: instead of complete?  I think that would process each as they process instead of waiting for all of them.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Just tried it, no change

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss `success` happens just before `complete`, they should behave the same.

Comment: See my answer for some detail but bottom line is `setTimeout(setProgress(), 1000)` is improper syntax.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I stared at this for a bit, and it just seems to have a large amount of issues/questions.  Putting this in as an answer as it it too large for comments.

1. Your setTimeout should be wrapped in a function; as written it is a syntax error:

   `setTimeout(function() { setProgress(); }, 1000);`
2. You have no getProgress() function, but, to me at least, it seems like the progress.php call should be IN that function, as it is, this makes no sense.  MY assumption here is that that ajax call to lines.php returns the number of lines (files) and progress is the number processed so far, and that should update the progress bar?  You also should have a percent of 100 calculation of the lines processed vs the number of files.  Thus if you have 40 files for instance, and you processed 10 so far, it would show 25 as the progress (40 divided by 10 is 25).  This allows you to simplify the setProgress() function as "prog" then automatically gets to 100 at the end:

   function setProgress() {
       var prog = getProgress();//does progress.php ajax call
       $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', prog);
       if (prog < 100){
           setTimeout(function() {setProgress();}, 1000);
       }
   }

2A  move one ajax call to process every second:

```
function getProgress() {
    var lines = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'progress.php',
        async: false,
        data: '{}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            lines = json.total;
        }
    });
    return lines;// should be 0 to 100 to show progress percent
};
```

1. Using `complete:` rather than `success:` - complete processes even if you get an error, but success does NOT, and you do not trap errors in your complete function.
2. Your call to the scrubber has no datatype, so it assumes json, do you really mean to append the querystring to the url string and have your data empty as: `data: '{}',` instead?  This is a wild assumption on my part as you do not list your `makeQS()` function.
3. Your call to the lines.php has no data and that can cause issues in some circumstances.  Put a empty one `data:'{}',` in there.
4. Your files array processing is not the most efficient:

   ```
   success: function() {
       var fileLength = files.length;//assumes files does not change, keeps loop from a lookup on every loop.
       for (var i = 0; i < fileLength; i++) {
           var myMatch = 'MATCHED - ' + files[i];//better string handling - do one time only
           var myScrub = 'SCRUBBED - ' + files[i];
           $('#complete').append('<a href="process/' + myMatch + '">' + myMatch + '</a><br />');
           $('#complete').append('<a href="process/' + myScrub + '">' + myScrub + '</a><br />');
       }
   }
   ```
5. You have a number of global variables which is generally not a great practice.  "col", "files", "lines" for instance.
6. Your "setTimeout" IN the setProgress is not properly terminated with a semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss . I am, admittedly a JavaScript/jQuery noob and have corrected all the examples you pointed out.  I mostly work on the server-side and database processing, normally.

However, the original question I solved this  morning after looking over the code... and it seems that `getProgress()` had a `$.ajax()` call with `async: false`.  It fixed the issue.  If you are interested, more on this project was discussed in this SO thread: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917052/ajax-call-wont-complete-until-previous-ajax-call-is-complete/8917184#8917184

Comment: I wondered IF that were true, and that would have stopped the processing (as the code I presented above HAS it such).