# .ajax() call won't complete until previous .ajax() call is complete?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So, i'm working on a progress bar for a CSV processing script.  `dnc_scrubber.php` goes through the CSV and checks a phone number against a database, returning matched and unmatched data in separate files.  `lines.php` returns the total amount of lines to be processed while `progress.php` returns how many lines have been worked through.  I use these two numbers to create a percentage of work done for jQuery's progressbar function.

My problem is that the first `.ajax()` call within `doProgressBar()` doesn't finish until the call to `dnc_scrubber.php` is finished.  To clarify, when looking at the network monitor in Chrome, the request is made to `lines.php` at the same time as the request to `dnc_scrubber.php`, but no response is received until `dnc_scrubber.php` finished running. Here is the relevant code:

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar();            


$.ajax({
url: 'dnc_scrubber.php',
type: 'POST',
async: true,
data: querystring,  
success: function(){
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        $('#complete').append('<a href="process/MATCHED - ' + files[i] + '">MATCHED - ' + files[i] + '</a><br />');
        $('#complete').append('<a href="process/SCRUBBED - ' + files[i] + '">SCRUBBED - ' + files[i] + '</a><br />');
    }
}                       
});


function doProgressBar(){                   
$.ajax({
    url: 'lines.php',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function (rez) {
        lines = JSON.parse(rez.responseText);
        lines = parseInt(lines.lines);

        console.log('dpg1 - lines: ' + lines);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'progress.php',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function (rez1) {
                prog = JSON.parse(rez1.responseText);
                prog = parseInt(prog.progress);

                console.log('dpg2 - lines: ' + lines + ' prog: ' + prog);

                if (lines > prog){
                    var bar = (prog / lines) * 100;                                         
                    var bar = Math.round(bar);                                          
                    $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', bar);
                    setTimeout(doProgressBar(), 1000);
                    console.log('dpg3 - lines: ' + lines + ' prog: ' + prog + ' bar: ' + bar);
                } else if (lines == prog){
                    $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', 100);
                    console.log('dpg3 - lines == prog');
                }

            }
        });

    }
});
}



setTimeout(doProgressBar(), 100);
```

Is this normal functionality? Is what I'm trying to do not possible?  I'm at a loss... thanks in advance for help

EDIT:
`lines.php`

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('lines' => $_SESSION['lines']));
```

`progress.php`

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('progress' => $_SESSION['lines_processed']));
```

The CSV processor increments the `$_SESSION['lines_proccessed']` by one at the end of the checking process for every line

Comment: how many connections is the server allowing at any given time?

Comment: @nobody the server is allowing a very large number of connections according to my IT guys.  It's an in-house Ubuntu development server running lampp - with mostly default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your server limits the number of concurrent connections per user to 1.  Or, you are using sessions and the first script has it locked.  The second script will be blocked until the first one releases its lock on the session file.  Only use `session_start()` if you need to, and release the lock with `session_write_close()` as soon as you are done with it.

**Edit:** I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try it.  Each time you want to update the session, call `session_start()`, update the session, then call `session_write_close()`.  I'm not sure if you are allowed to do that multiple times in a script, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: nice one. Hadn't though of that but it's even more plausible than my answer. Gonna leave mine just in case... but thumbs up here.

Comment: @Frankie - Funny, I had the same thought about *your* answer.  It's tough to say which it is without seeing the php code.

Comment: I am using sessions. I use `session_start()` on all involved files.  `dnc_scrubber.php` sets `$_SESSION['lines']` which is read by `lines.php`.  It also updates `$_SESSION['lines_processed']` as it goes through the lines of the CSV.  `progress.php` returns that session variable.

That is probably the source of my issue.  Do you have any suggestions as to a better way to track progress?

Comment: @Obi-wanJacobi - I updated my answer with something you can try.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the exact cause of your problem, but it is something that needs fixed.

Change

```
setTimeout(doProgressBar(), 100);
```

To

```
setTimeout(doProgressBar, 100);
```

You are calling doProgressBar immediately, not after the timeout is complete.

Comment: Thanks, I will make that change

Answer (score 1):

Ajax would be assync.

`lines.php` is probably waiting on `dnc_scrubber.php` as the first one has locked MySQL.

This is just guessing as we don't have your PHP code but try to run both PHP scripts manually and check if `lines.php` doesn't wait for MySQL to finish.

Comment: `lines.php` just returns a session variable as JSON

Comment: @Obi-wan Jacobi then check gilly3 answer. Gonna leave mine just in case someone Google's by and has a different issue but I think he nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

when reading your .csv file with your PHP code is it locking the file? so if it has to read it twice, it will only read it when the previous code closes the stream?

what happens if you open 2 browsers and run the code at the same time? do both browsers execute at the same time with the same results? or is there a wait on the file?